# Instantiation of chaincode onto different channels on Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, google-kubernetes-engine, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I tried to create a separate channel and instantiate separate chaincodes onto the channel. I was able to create separate channels but when I instantiate the chaincode onto the cahnnels, both the chaincodes are being instantiated on both the channels created.

Even though I have set the environment variable for CHANNEL_NAME: "channel2" and CHAINCODE_NAME: "arm2", both the chaincodes are instantiated on both channels.

Here is the yaml code for chaincode instantiation of instantiating chaincode "arm2" on the channel "channel2".

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: chaincodeinstantiate2
spec:
  backoffLimit: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: chaincodeinstantiate2
    spec:
      restartPolicy: "Never"
      volumes:
      - name: nfs
        nfs:
          server: %NFS_CLUSTER_IP%
          path: /
      containers:
      - name: chaincodeinstantiate2
        image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:x86_64-1.0.4
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["sh", "-c", "peer chaincode instantiate -o blockchain-orderer:31010 -C ${CHANNEL_NAME} -n ${CHAINCODE_NAME} -v ${CHAINCODE_VERSION} -c '{\"Args\":[\"init\",\"a\",\"100\",\"b\",\"200\"]}'"]
        env:
        - name: CHANNEL_NAME
          value: channel2
        - name: CHAINCODE_NAME
          value: "arm2"
        - name: CHAINCODE_VERSION
          value: "1.0"
        - name: FABRIC_CFG_PATH
          value: /etc/hyperledger/fabric
        - name: CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH
          value: /shared/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
        - name: CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID
          value: Org1MSP
        - name: CORE_PEER_ADDRESS
          value: blockchain-org1peer1:30110
        - name: GODEBUG
          value: "netdns=go"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /shared
          name: nfs
```

The image attached shows the chaincodes database which contains four rows consisting of chaincodes "arm1" and "arm2" on both channels "channel1" and "channel2".

[image: image attached shows the chaincodes database which contains four rows consisting of chaincodes "arm1" and "arm2" on both channels "channel1" and "channel2"]

How do I instantiate the chaincode "arm1" onto only channel "channel1" and chaincode "arm2" onto only channel "channel2"?

Comment: Please don't include pictures of your code and data. You should copy and paste it into your question so that others can reproduce your results.